# Interpretation of a Parabolic Partial Differential Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$ ($d\geq 1$) be a bounded domain with a smooth boundary $\partial\Omega$. Let $S, I$ be dependent variables and $x, t$ their independent variables. Additionally, $q:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function taking positive bounded values.

What could be a mathematical interpretation of the following Partial Differential Equation (which actually is part of a particular SIR model)?

$\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial t}-\triangle S = aq(t)-aS+bI-\gamma\dfrac{SI}{N} \text{   in } \Omega\times(t_{0}, +\infty)$

I hold an interpretation for all the mathematical factors (symbols) that make up the equation, but I cannot interpret holistically (and mathematically) the equation (which may imply that I understand it). And it would be awesome if someone could recommend me a book about interpretations of equations.

P.S.: This is what I've got so far:

$S(x,t):$ number of susceptible (not infected but able to be it) individuals at time $t$ and position $x$.

$\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial t}:$ represents the growth rate of S over time.

$\triangle S:$ measure of the state of being concave of the graph of S(x,t). Informally, difference between the average value of $S$ in the neighborhood of a point, and its value at that point.

$a:$ the average number of deaths caused by the disease per person per unit of time.

$b:$ the average excess deaths caused by the disease per infected person per unit of time.

$\gamma:$ average number of contacts between susceptible and infected people.

$q(t):$ seasonal variation of transmission.

Thank for your time.

Comment: Does $\triangle S = \nabla^2 S$?

Comment: It is the Laplacian operator of S.

Comment: If it is the Laplacian of $S$, what are the independent variables? $x$ and $t$?  So the Laplacian is with respect to the spatial variables?

Comment: I've typed them in. $x, t$ are the independent variables.

Comment: Where did you get this variant of the SIR model?  Any links, citings or papers?

Comment: You can check the system from: "Uniform boundedness of the attractor in $H^{2}$ of a non-autonomous epidemiological system" by Anguiano (2018). https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01425151/document

Comment: I checked the paper.  Very engaging.  Thanks so much.  Great and timely question, ***+1, endorsed!***

Comment: I still need help with this...someone?

Comment: I have been reading the paper you cited and thinking about your question.  It is deep.  Hopefully I will be able to say something before too long.  Cheers!